# MacBook Air M1 - no compatible Gpu

Tags: osx

I just download the last version blender-3.1.0-macos-arm64.
I've tried to setup the gpu with metal but I can't select the gpu as mentioned.

is there something else I need to do?
thanks

[image]

---

**SOLVED**

File > Defaults > Load Factory Setting

blender Icon -> System -> clean up space data

Comment: is there a reason why you didn't download the apple silikon version which would be right for your M1 ?

Comment: hi Chris, arm64 stands for the m1 ;) the other one is intel64

Comment: so you downloaded here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwNCD.jpg the apple silicon version? because your error message tells something else so i wonder....

Comment: @tylyo feel free to post that as an answer to your own question, and then after some delay you can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

File > Defaults > Load Factory Setting

blender Icon -> System -> clean up space data